# Unevenly spaced and overlapping lines for proportional stacked area graph on ggplot2 R

Tags: r, ggplot2, area, stacked

I'm trying to create a proportional stacked area graph as shown below in my mock data (Figure 1). When I try to do this with my real data, it comes out to Figure 2.

The class of the data are all the same after converting to percentages between the mock and 16S and are as follows: Timepoint - integer, Taxa - character, n - integer, percentage - numeric.

I'm looking to get the x-axis treated categorically and numerically (for two separate graphs) in the 16S data as with the mock and also to tidy up the overlapping lines (e.g., aesthetically the plot for 16S will look like the mock data).

```
dput(S1_RA1[1:40,])
 structure(list(Timepoint = c(-10L, -10L, -10L, -10L, -10L, -10L, 
-10L, -10L, -10L, -3L, -3L, -3L, -3L, -3L, -3L, -3L, -3L, -3L, 
-3L, -3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Taxa = c(" Anaerococcus", " Bacteroides", 
" Bifidobacterium", " Bilophila", " Collinsella", " Lachnoclostridium", 
" Streptococcus", " Veillonella", "Enterobacter", " Acinetobacter", 
" Anaerococcus", " Bacteroides", " Bifidobacterium", " Escherichia-Shigella", 
" Flavobacterium", " Lachnoclostridium", " Parabacteroides", 
" Peptoniphilus", " Veillonella", "Enterobacter", " Acinetobacter", 
" Bacteroides", " Bifidobacterium", " Bilophila", " Collinsella", 
" Desemzia", " Escherichia-Shigella", " Lachnoclostridium", " Parabacteroides", 
" Streptococcus", " Veillonella", " Bacteroides", " Bifidobacterium", 
" Bilophila", " Desemzia", " Escherichia-Shigella", " Lachnoclostridium", 
" Parabacteroides", " Streptococcus", " Veillonella"), n = c(40L, 
2188L, 665L, 84L, 55L, 131L, 153L, 11325L, 185L, 127L, 62L, 1123L, 
172L, 63L, 2L, 118L, 100L, 9L, 23123L, 109L, 253L, 2658L, 348L, 
163L, 204L, 27L, 163L, 245L, 290L, 41L, 17497L, 2325L, 50L, 197L, 
13L, 255L, 152L, 478L, 92L, 19692L), percentage = c(0.00269796303790638, 
0.147578578173479, 0.0448536355051936, 0.0056657223796034, 0.00370969917712127, 
0.0088358289491434, 0.0103197086199919, 0.763860785107244, 0.012478079050317, 
0.00507837492002559, 0.00247920665387076, 0.0449056301983365, 
0.00687779910428663, 0.00251919385796545, 7.99744081893794e-05, 
0.00471849008317338, 0.00399872040946897, 0.000359884836852207, 
0.92462412028151, 0.00435860524632118, 0.0115583169628581, 0.121430855680936, 
0.0158983964548403, 0.0074466627072959, 0.00931974964594088, 
0.00123349627666865, 0.0074466627072959, 0.0111928365845859, 
0.0132486637123669, 0.00187308693864498, 0.799351272328567, 0.0978823727529154, 
0.00210499726350356, 0.00829368921820402, 0.000547299288510925, 
0.0107354860438681, 0.00639919168105081, 0.020123773839094, 0.00387319496484655, 
0.829032122258241)), row.names = c(NA, -40L), groups = structure(list(
    Timepoint = c(-10L, -3L, 0L, 1L), .rows = structure(list(
        1:9, 10:20, 21:31, 32:40), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I've tried the following:

1. Setting the scale_x_discrete to scale_x_continuous
2. Converting aes(x = as.factor(Timepoint)..
3. Changing the limits/expand parameters in the scale_x_discrete code
4. Removing the negative timepoints
5. Changing the Number column in the S1_RA2 file to match the number system in Table 1

My code for the 16S is as follows and is almost identical to the mock except for the colors:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
RA1 <- read.csv("RA1.csv", header=TRUE)

#Transform relative abundance from RA1.csv to percentages
S1_RA1 <- RA1 %>%
  group_by(Timepoint, Taxa) %>%
  summarise(n = sum(Relative.Abundance)) %>%
  mutate (percentage = n / sum(n))
head(Shime1_RA2)

#Set color palette to be able to include 15 colors
nb.cols <- 16
getPalette <- colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(9, 'Set1'))(nb.cols)



#Revised code - The code below works courtesy of Gregor's comment
 library(tidyr)
Shime1_RA2 <- Shime1_RA2 %>% ungroup %>%
  complete(Timepoint, Taxa, fill = list(n = 0, percentage = 0))

ggplot(Shime1_RA2, aes(x = factor(Timepoint), y = percentage, fill = Taxa, group = Taxa)) +
  geom_area(position = "fill", colour = "black", size = .5, alpha = .7) +
  scale_y_continuous(name="Relative Abundance", expand=c(0,0)) +
  scale_x_discrete(name="Timepoint (d)", expand=c(0,0)) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = getPalette) + 
  theme(legend.position='bottom')
```

[image: Figure 1. Proportional stacked area graph of mock 16S data]

[image: Figure 2]

Comment: Where is your mock data? What is the class of the `Timepoint` column in your mock data? What is the class of the `Timepoint` column in your real data? You say the "class are all the same" but you don't say what class it is...

Comment: In terms of your x-axis scale, what do you **want**? Your mock data seems to have Timepoint values 1, 2, 3, ..., 10 -- nice, evenly spaced numbers. Your real data has a handful of values between -10 and 16, not evenly spaced. Do you want them treated categorically (the same distance between adjacent unique values: the same space between -10 and -3 as between 1 and 2?) or do you want them treated numerically, where -10 is way off to the left?

Comment: And, it's much preferable to share data in the question directly rather than put it in a link. Links go dead, making questions unusable resources. It's also (a little bit) more work to download a file, point R to your download folder, read it in, reset R's working directory and delete the file when done,  than a simple copy/paste. It'd be nicer if you put a small sample of data in the question, like `dput(S1_RA1[1:20, ])` for the first 20 rows (choose an illustrative subset -- 3 categories at 4 timepoints should be plenty).

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I've updated my post to include the following:
Classes of the variables after converting to percentage, what I'm hoping to achieve in the 16S graph, x-axis evenly spaced, and i posted the data as dput[1:40] as you suggested.

Comment: Thanks for being so receptive to the feedback!

Comment: Or you can use `na.translate = FALSE` in `scale_x_discrete` to automatically remove the `NA` rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed three things:

1. You want the x-scale to be treated categorically, so we need to `factor(Timepoint)`. (And then the default scale will be fine, so we delete your manually specified `limits`l)
2. When we use a discrete x-axis scale, we have to explicitly tell `ggplot` which dots we want to connect. We do this by adding the `group = Taxa` aesthetic.
3. The weird lines cutting through the middle of other polygons are because you don't have an observation for every taxa at every timepoint, so when the dots are connected they may cut through intermediate timepoints. Use `tidyr::complete` to fill in the missing observations with 0s.

```
library(tidyr)
S1_RA1 = S1_RA1 %>% ungroup %>%
  complete(Timepoint, Taxa, fill = list(n = 0, percentage = 0))

ggplot(S1_RA1, aes(x = factor(Timepoint), y = percentage, fill = Taxa, group = Taxa)) +
  geom_area(position = "fill", colour = "black", size = .5, alpha = .7) +
  scale_y_continuous(name="Relative Abundance", expand=c(0,0)) +
  scale_x_discrete(
    name="Timepoint (d)", expand=c(0,0) 
  ) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = getPalette) + 
  theme(legend.position='bottom')
```

[image]